# Xerces-C: Parse Javascript inside of HTML

Tags: c++, html, xml, xerces, xerces-c

I want to parse websites for their meta tags. For this I use xerces-c.

```
shared_ptr<SAX2XMLReader> parser(XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader());

//Create and set callback handler with the given callback functions
Handler handler(startElement,endElement,characters);
parser->setContentHandler(&handler);
parser->setErrorHandler(&handler);

//Parse the file with the given callback handler
parser->parse(filename.c_str());
```

Some websites now have javascript on it. Inside of the script tags javascript uses the operator && for logical and.

Xerces-C interprets this as entity reference (for example &nbsp) and throws an exception, because it doesn't know the entity reference &&.

Is there a way to read this correctly as text?

Or if not - is there a way to just ignore all characters inside of script tags? I don't need them anyway. I just want to parse the meta tags.

Comment: Is it a good idea to parse HTML with an XML parser unless it is XHTML ? The Javascript should be properly escaped in a CDATA section or I think you will have to make a first pass on the HTML/JS code to clean it before passing it through Xerces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `html` is not necessarily well-formed `xml`, but you can, for instance, preprocess it with [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) before feeding to xml parser.